# jQuery Two functions at the same time

Tags: jquery, function, time

I have a problem, I am developing a website, that should update an inbox every x amount of seconds what I do with jquery (jquery.timers), of the code that it is generated there is a button that when pressed it, should show me a table (jquery.fancybox). the problem not showing me the box, now if I delete the timer if me displays the dialog box. the timer works or works the fancybox, but not both. I leave the code to know if there is something wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
  j(document).ready(function()
  {
    j("#caja-scroll").everyTime(2000,function(i){
        j.ajax({
            url: "php/inbox.php", 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                j("#caja-scroll").html(html);
            }
        })
    })
  }); 

    jQuery(".btnGestionar").click( function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/act_gestion.php?id="+currentId+"&accion=open",
    success: function(datos){
        if (datos == "ocupado"){
            $('#btnPopAlerta').fancybox({
                'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' :'elastic',
                'onClosed': function(){
                    location.href='index.php?go=2';
                }
            }).trigger('click');
        }else if (datos == "abierto"){
            $('#btnGestionarH').fancybox({
                'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' :'elastic',
                'onClosed':function(){
                    /* event */
                });
            }).trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

Comment: you should edit this post and reformat the code for proper indenting. it is painful to read like this.

Comment: ... what? If you're asking about the downvote it wasn't me. I don't know what your comment means. I'm just saying it is very difficult to read your code like this. Nobody likes scrolling horizontally to read what could be very clear if it was just formatted like normal code. If you want answers, post your question in a way you would want to see if it was being asked of you.

Comment: ok. it's done i wish it could be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code had a $(document).ready() call in a $(document).ready() call.

You are also missing at least two `;` and it also looks like you may have a few of your brackets and/or parenthesis in the wrong place.  This version should be your code, cleaned up:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function() {
    j("#caja-scroll").everyTime(2000,function(i) {
        j.ajax({
            url: "php/inbox.php", 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                j("#caja-scroll").html(html);
            }
        });
    });

    j(".btnGestionar").click( function() {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        j.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "php/act_gestion.php?id="+currentId+"&accion=open",
            success: function(datos){
                if (datos == "ocupado"){
                    j('#btnPopAlerta').fancybox({
                        'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut' :'elastic',
                        'onClosed': function(){
                            location.href='index.php?go=2';
                        }
                    }).trigger('click');
                } else if (datos == "abierto") {
                    j('#btnGestionarH').fancybox({
                        'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut' :'elastic',
                        'onClosed': function(){
                            /* event */
                        }
                    }).trigger('click');
                }
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Also note that since you were using `j` as the variable to denote the `jQuery` function instead of `$`, I replaced all instances of `jQuery()` and `$` with `j`